# Are pure virtual functions early binding (compile time) or late binding (run time)?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, vtable, pure-virtual

I see in various online resources that `virtual functions` are runtime bound.

However a `pure virtual function` must be implemented in a derived class. So, it doesn't make sense to me why a `vtable` would be needed in that scenario. Therefore I was wondering if a `pure virtual function` is bound at runtime or compile time.

If it is bound at runtime, is it just for the case that a `pure virtual function` has an implementation and the derived class calls the base implementation? What happens if no implementation is provided? Does the compiler then `inline` the implementation?

Comment: @iz_  According to this example, it can be implemented in the base class https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/abstract_classes

Comment: @TerenceChow My bad, then. However, the base class version of the function will never be called implicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already found out, virtual functions are resolved at runtime. You need a vtable for this situation:

```cpp
class Parent {
 public:
  virtual void pure() = 0;
};

class Child : public Parent {
 public:
  void pure() {}
};

void do_pure(Parent& x){
   x.pure();
}

int main(){
  do_pure(Child());
}
```

The `Child()` instance is cast to a `Parent` when it is passed to `do_pure`. The vtable is then required for the line `x.pure()` to be able to locate the memory adress of the implementation of `pure()`.

If `Child` wouldn't implement `do_pure`, this wouldn't compile, because the line `x.pure()` could only crash.

Comment: So if you did not have any casting to the parent, and simply called `Child().pure()` in main, would a compiler be smart enough to simply do away with the vtable?

Comment: @TerenceChow The vtable would still be present in the (temporary) `Child()` object, but the function call to `pure` could be made without using the vtable because the full object type is known.

Comment: Godbold says yes: https://godbolt.org/z/DVr546. The whole temporary object is optimized away.

Comment: devirtualization is gaining traction thanks to `final`, so it's not entirely accurate to say they're resolved at runtime fullstop.

Comment: The vtable isn't in the object. A pointer to to is in the object.

Answer (score 0):

All `virtual` functions need to have late binding.

Imagine the following class hierarchy:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

struct Child: public Base {
    void foo() override { std::cout << "I'm good!"; }
};

struct Grandchild: public Child {
    void foo() final { std::cout << "But I'm better!"; }
};

void fooCaller(const Base& b) {
    //Which foo() do I call here? Child::foo() or Grandchild::foo()?
    b.foo();
}

int main() {
    Grandchild g;
    fooCaller(g);
}
```

A `virtual` function remains virtual in *all* derived classes, which means you can override is anywhere you want (unless it's declared `final` at some point). Compiler cannot know which version will be in use.

In theory, if we have `virtual void foo() = 0;` in `Base` and `void foo() final;` in `Child`, compiler could notice that there is only one possible implementation of `foo` and optimize it out of the vtable, but I never heard about any compiler doing that.
And such use case kind of defeats the purpose of pure virtual functions.

Comment: It cannot be marked as final in the base class, as there are no pure final virtual functions. Thus a class that inherits from the base could override it.

Comment: @Chronial It may be weird, but standard doesn't forbid pure virtual final functions (see syntax #1 in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) ). What I meant is that first class that provides an implementation for the pure virtual function (probably the `Child`), also marks it as `final`, I'll try to clarify that more.

Comment: devirtualization is gaining traction thanks to `final`, so it's not entirely accurate to say they're "all" late binding.